# Disable multiple cursors in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was playing on my vscode configurations and accidentally change some configuration when I want to select the text on my code lines.

For example, when I want to select some lines in my code immediately appears a lot of cursors instead of selecting the text that I wanted. How can I change this configuration? Because a few days ago the selection in VSCode worked properly.

As you can see on the screenshot below, this happens when I try to select those lines :(

[image: screenshot with the problem in vscode]

Comment: You are probably clicking with the middle click button. This could be caused by a strange mouse. have you tried with a different mouse? It doesn't use multiple cursors normally when selecting. If you middle click and drag, it makes many cursors.

If  you don't know, middle click is clicking with the scroll wheel/scroll ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `Column Selection Mode`

From the main menu: `Selection/Column Selection Mode` uncheck

or there  should be a `Column Selection` button on the Status Bar to the right that can be disabled.